# Upgrading ts-loader to awesome-typescript-loader doesn't load components

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to upgade to awesome-typescript-loader from ts-loader, however countering the problem where templates are not loaded. Not sure what to look into.

```
zone.js?fad3:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load nav-menu.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load nav-menu.component.html undefined
```

Version:

```
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4"
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just swapped the order of the loaders in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: ['angular2-template-loader', 'awesome-typescript-loader']
}
```

So `'angular2-template-loader'` comes before the `'awesome-typescript-loader'`.
I have no idea why it worked.

Comment: Webpack loaders are executed from right to left, so *the order matters*. `angular2-template-loader` expects JavaScript code. If the file is not processed by `awesome-typescript-loader` before, then it'd fail as it'd receive `TypeScript` code.